# Add equal distance between UILabels using Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a UISlider with labels below it, ranging from 1 to 10.

----------------------   (UISlider)
 1    2     3    4    5     6     7    8     9     10  (Labels)

I want to add constraints on the labels so that they look right in both Landscape and Portrait modes. How do I add constraints such that the labels are equally spaced out below the slider?

Comment: Apple [recommends creating a spacer view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW8) between each label, and creating constraints for each to be equal width, then set vertical space to the container and horizontal space to each spacer -> view -> spacer, etc.  See

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) place your buttons so that they match they future position as much as possible.

1) Set all buttons to have their title label texts centered.

2) Set autolayout constraints - all buttons to have leading and trailing margins to have the same value. (do this one by one)

3) Set autolayout constraints - all buttons to have the same width. (select all buttons and do it at once)

Comment: As a courtesy, please mark the answer as correct by green check mark right under the arrows and number.